# SFTP doesn't work with encoded password

Tags: sftp

We use SFTP in our project to transfer files over an SSH connection. This is done through java code. Assuming that if for characters like ?, ! etc we need to give the encoded value in the sftp command, we encoded the password in the code and generated the command. But SFTP isn't working with these encoded password now, it accepts the password directly. What could be the issue. Please help.

Example username: xyz password: abc!

We use URLEncoder to encode the username and password.

String username= URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8"); 
String password = URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

After encoding Our code would generate SFTP command as : sftp://xyz:abc%21@10.9.10.9/home/documents/xyz.txt

But this isn't working, Authentication fails with wrong password. Where as manually if we give command sftp://xyz:abc!@10.9.10.9/home/documents/xyz.txt it works.

Please let us know if we are going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with: "Assuming that if for characters like ?, ! etc we need to give the encoded value in the sftp command"? What are the additional requirements that you have?

Comment: Included code for clarity.

Comment: What tools do you use to connect to SFTP, and how you call them?

Comment: Obviously the SFTP client doesn't decode the provided password. You can change the client to something more flexible.

Comment: We donot have the SFTP client in our control, its handled by other team. I am not pretty familiar with how SFTP works, does it decode the password ALWAYS or is it SFTP client specific? Our app will be used by many users, so how can we make it more generic?

Comment: Maybe don't urlencode the password then? Just because you're doing URLEncoding doesn't mean the SFTP client is and certainly the server wouldn't be lest it be in violation of the SSH2 spec.

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky, he is probably using WinSCP: https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=108619#108619

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not actually an issue. SFTP is a subsystem of SSH, and SSH creates a secure channel upon client connection (similarly to what SSL does but at layer 7): once the secure and encrypted connection is established, your username and password will be sent to the SSH server inside such connection, therefore there is no need to encode them nor to encrypt them.

**The SSH server expects to receive your username/password as they are, not pre-processed nor encoded**. And you can do that safely with SFTP for the reason explained here above. So no reason to be worried.